# creating lists in java

Tags: java, eclipse, list

So I am pretty new to java, and am trying to create a list in java with this:

```
private creatureKind[] field = new creatureKind[7];
```

`creatureKind` being another class I created within the same package. Is this the right syntax? I am trying to call functions such as `set()`, which

I found on this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-, but I am getting an error message that abridged is saying that field is an array type. Not a frequent poster of this site so sorry if I messed stuff up in advance.

Comment: Your confused over the different between `List` and arrays. I would suggest you start by having a look at the [Arrays tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and the [Collections tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) to gain a better understand between the two

Comment: I think you should take a look through Java’s ArrayList and Arrays API.  Also that line doesn’t make any sense, could you explain more and provide more code? Are you trying to have an Array of Ints, doubles, strings, chars???

Comment: hey EOxJ i am trying to create a list of objects called creatureKind which is a class i made in the same package in where this line of code is located

Answer (score 0):

What you defined is a static array with a 7 element.
If you want to define a list, or better, an ArrayList you should it as follows:

```
List<creatureKind> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note that this is an unbound list, you should add values, before setting values. In general, I would suggest reading the documentations: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you might need to do the following:

```
List<creatureKind> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```